# Find the Missing Members of this Powered Sequence

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

There are 4 missing members in this small series...labeled ???.

Hint 1;

> When you need assistance, seek help from higher authority.

Hint 2:

> Higher authority can grant you higher powers!

Complete the series.

$191$, $426$, $931$, $???$, $???$, $646$, $971$, $???$, $???$

Comment: If nobody gets it by tomorrow, I will drop a Hint.

Comment: Going to provide the first hint now.

Comment: Second hint is being given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is:

> 191, 426, 931, 666, 555, 646, 971, 486, 111

Explanation:

> For the nth number:
>
>  The first digit is: $n^2 \bmod 10$.
>  The second digit is: $10 - (n^3 \bmod 10)$.
>  The third digit is: $n^4 \bmod 10$.
>
>  Example: eighth number
>
>  First digit is: $8^2 \bmod 10 = 64 \bmod 10 = 4$
>  Second digit is: $10 - (8^3 \bmod 10) = 10 - (512 \bmod 10) = 10 - 2 = 8$
>  Third digit is: $8^4 \bmod 10 = 4096 \bmod 10 = 6$
>  Final number: $486$

Answer (score 5):

Complete answer.

> 191, 426, 931, 626, 591, 646, 971, 486, 191

because

> First digits are the square numbers modulo 10 (1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 4, 1) and last digits alternate between 1 and 6. Respectively, the sum of all the digits add up to 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 and cycle back to 11 since the last term is the same as the starting one.

Comment: nice progress and approach, +1!

Comment: any ideas? mine wont work...

Comment: All I can say is that you are on the right track partially.

Answer (score 1):

191, 426, 931, ???, ???, 646, 971, ???, ???

After looking for few minute I found pattern as

> 1.Sum of digit in series as 11,12,13, ???, ???,16,17,???, ???
>
> 2.the first digit: square of series 1,4,9,1(6),2(5),3(6),4(9),6(4),8(1)
>
> 3.the last digit is flipping between 1& 6

So using 1&2&3 pattern :626,591,486,991

Comment: Not right..will post a hint tomorrow if nobody gets it by that time